# Swift: For-in loop non-inclusive upper on PlayGround

Tags: swift, for-in-loop

I have just started playing with Swift. When using a Playground, according to Apple's iBook the following should work:

```
var firstForLoop = 0;

for i in 1..3 {
    firstForLoop += i;
}
```

However, the interpreter is complaining: "Use of unresolved identifier '..'"
I have tried:

```
var firstForLoop = 0;

for i in 1...3 {
    firstForLoop += i;
}
```

and it works just fine (including the upper value in the loop). Has Apple removed the `..` option from Swift's grammar?

Answer (score 15):

`..` is now `..<`.

You're probably using an old version of the book.